# Prevent onbeforeunload alert using jquery in Firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, onbeforeunload

I have used `onbeforeunload` event to show a default alert box when user tries to leave the page.

This dialog is showing in my Form Post action.

I have used `event.preventDefault()` (for browsers except safari) and `return null` for Safari to prevent showing this dialog in Form post action. But this is not working in firefox and IE.

Below is the jquery code sample

```
if (!isSafari) {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
            if (!hideDefaultAlert) {
                event.returnValue = "Your unsaved changes will be lost";
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                hideDefaultAlert = false;
            }
        });
    } else if (isSafari) {
        $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
            if (!hideDefaultAlert) {
                return "Your unsaved changes will be lost";
            } else {
                hideDefaultAlert = false;
                return null;
            }           
        });
    }
```

Please provide a solution for this to prevent this alert in Firefox and Safari.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you check whether the browser is Safari? In IE and Firefox, try to set break point in the beforeunload function and check whether the code is executed.

Comment: Code used to check safari browser 

var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf("Constructor") > 0;

yes, i checked setting the break point, and code is executed. but still the alert box is shown for form post action request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this is, need to replace `event.preventDefault()` with `event.stopPropagation()` and `return undefined`. This solution works in all the browser.

```
if (!isSafari) {
        window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
            if (!hideDefaultAlert) {
                event.returnValue = "Your unsaved changes will be lost";
            } else {
                event.stopPropagation();
                hideDefaultAlert = false;
                return undefined;
            }
        });
    } else if (isSafari) {
        $(window).on("beforeunload", function () {
            if (!hideDefaultAlert) {
                return "Your unsaved changes will be lost";
            } else {
                hideDefaultAlert = false;
                return null;
            }           
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the browser is not Safari and if the form is not changed, there is no need to display the dialog. So, please try to modify your code as below (remove the event.preventDefault()):

```
        var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf("Constructor") > 0;
        var hideDefaultAlert = true;
        if (!isSafari) {
            alert("not safari");
            window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
                if (!hideDefaultAlert) {
                    event.returnValue = "Your unsaved changes will be lost";
                } else {
                    //event.preventDefault(); //remove this line
                    hideDefaultAlert = false;
                }
            });
        }
```